# MongoDB 3.2 Equivalent of the $mergeObjects Stage

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using the $facet operator in my MongoDB view to run two pipelines on the same data. In the final stage I need to merge these two back together. If we were running Mongo 3.6 I'd use the $mergeObjects operator to do this. However, we're running version 3.2, where $mergeObjects isn't available. So I'm trying to figure out what the 3.2 equivalent of this would be:

```
{
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: {
      $mergeObjects: ["$pipelineResults", {
        totalCount: "$totalCount.value"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried using $project, like this:

```
{
  newRoot: {
    $project: {
      "$pipelineResults": 1,
      totalCount: {
        "$totalCount.value": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... but this doesn't work. Maybe I need a combination of $group and $project? What would this look like in 3.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 3.2 then you can't use `$mergeObjects` as well (available since 3.6). In fact these two operators are just a convenient way of projecting so you can replace them with `$project` but the downside is that you have to specify all object properties like:

```
{
    $project: {
        fieldOne: "$pipelineResults.fieldOne",
        fieldTwo: "$pipelineResults.fieldTwo",
        //...
        totalCount: "$totalCount.value"
    }
}
```

Comment: "$mergeObjects" pipeline operator is available since 3.6, not 3.4.